# React Parent value to Child component as variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am passing a boolean value from parent to child component, it is working fine. And in child component, trying to store that boolean value to a variable to define a if condition. It is not working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from "./data/data";

function NavElements(props) {
//const isEditMode = false; //When the value is static it is working fine.

const isEditMode = {this.props.data}; //value is boolean data. This is not working.
if(isEditMode) {
return (
 (null)
);
}

return (
 <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
     {
      Object.keys(data).map((value, index) => {
        return (
           <li key={value} className="nav-item active">                        
                <a className="nav-link" href="#"> {value} <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li> 
        );
      })
      }
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </nav>
)
}
class Nav extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    {this.props.data} //same boolean data, this is working
    <NavElements />
  </div>

);
}
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a functional component, you should not use this in functional component,
us this line

const {isEditMode} = props.data

Comment: const isEditMode = props.editModeState;

  console.log('> ' + isEditMode);

console says : > Undefined

Comment: const {isEditMode} = props.editModeState;

console.log('> ' + isEditMode);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEditMode' of undefined

Comment: may be you are not pass data as a prop

Comment: handleEditClick(event) {
    this.props.callbackEditMode("true");    
  }

  handleViewClick(event) {
    this.props.callbackEditMode("false");
  }

Not able to pass true or false as boolean, instead passing as string is this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since that is functional components, `const isEditMode = {this.props.data}`;  `this` doesnt refer to the function rather its prototype, so try `const isEditMode = props.data.isEditMode;`

Comment: It says: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEditMode' of undefined

Comment: I tried const isEditMode = props.data;

console.log('> ' + isEditMode);

Console says: > Undefined

Answer (score 0):

Pass the props to NavElements like this:

And access it like this:
{props.data} and not{this.props.data} as it is a functional component.

Comment: Replace <NavElements /> with <NavElements {...this.props} />

Answer (score 0):

Parent

```
class Nav extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <NavElements data={this.props.data}/>
  </div>

);
}
}
```

in child access like this if it's functional component.

```
props.data
```

or

```
this.props.data   // if class based component
```